# Not printing the data from DataGridView but shown in PrintPreview

Tags: c#, datagridview

In the below code in print preview it is showing all the data from DataGridView  but not printing the all the data just printing the structure of page

I have attached image of both print preview and the printout

[image: Print preview]

```
private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    i = 0;
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Purchase Order ", new Font("Arial", 28, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(280, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("POPULAR ", new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 50));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Center", new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 80));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Behind ,", new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 100));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(" Colony,", new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 120));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Sh - 501.", new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 140));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("TIN    : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 160));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("GST   : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 178));

    e.Graphics.DrawString("P O No. : " + lblPONumber.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 197));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Date : " + date.Text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(506, 197));

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Name : " + txtSupplierName.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 70));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Company Name : " + txtSupplierCompanyName.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 90));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Mobile No.           : " + txtMobile.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 110));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Address               : ", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 130));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("                              ", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 150));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("City                       : ", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(420, 170));


    e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 210));

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Sl No.", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(05, 227));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Item Name", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(55, 225));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantity", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(380, 225));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Unit Price", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(510, 225));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(660, 225));

    e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 235));

    int ypos = 250;

    while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    {

        if (ypos > e.MarginBounds.Height)
        {
            ypos = 250;
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            return;
        }
            numberofitemsprinted++;
            SlNumber++;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(SlNumber.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, ypos));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(60, ypos));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(397, ypos));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(530, ypos));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(670, ypos));

                i++;
                ypos = ypos + 30;

    }




        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, ypos));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Amount      :       " + txtTotalSum.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(510, ypos + 30));


        e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount in Words      :       " + txtTotalSumWords.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(200, ypos + 120));



        numberofitemsperpage = 0;
        numberofitemsprinted = 0;
        SlNumber = 0;


    }

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the variable `i` before the printing.

It looks as if the `PrintPage` is called **once** for the preview and then, without `i` being reset, **again** for the actual printing..

This should help:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```

I would also **strongly** suggest to change the name `i` to something more explicit like `currentPrintRow`..

Comment: Thanks you very much @TaW

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: Yes brother @Taw  with your suggestion i got the answer and i thanked you for it, but i didn't knew how to accept it as answer so added the comment.